# Splitting a Tmap output into several tables based on the value of a column

Tags: talend

I have an output of `tmap` below is:

```
|src_table|src_columname
--------------------------
|Account  |ID          
|Account  |Name        
|Account  |Owner        
|Contact  |ID          
|Contact  |Name         
|Contact  |FirstName   
|Contact  |LastName
```

I want output in two table like first Account and second Contact

```
Account 
-----------------
ID |Name |Owner  |

Contact
-------------------------------      
ID |Name |FirstName |LastName  |
```

I am beginer in taled. Please tell me which component i need to use for above output.

[image: Pls click here]

Actually, I am not an expert user and I don't found my solution. scenario is:
I'm trying to migrate some 10 tables from SQL server dB to oracle server DB and i wish to use Talend but I don't know in which way I could make it. First I tried by below method: I have created many sub-jobs for mapping table by table in one job, because each table has a different table structure, I have created different sub job with the corresponding schema, for example tOracleInput_1--main tMSSQLOutput_1 (migrate table1) |

```
 onsubjobok |

 tOracleInput_2--main--tMSSQLOutput_2 (migrate table2) |

 onsubjobok |


 ...other subjobs for other tables...

But I do not want to create many sub job. is there any way like i need to create one subjob for all tables?
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use multiple outputs in tMap, and use the filter option in it.
Add a second output to your tMap .
Then activate a filter on both outputs (filter button in the yellow bar title)

In output #1, put a filter on src_table, like `"Account".equals(row2.src_table)`

In output #2, put a filter on src_table, like `"Contact".equals(row2.src_table)`

Then you will have only Accounts in your first output, only Contacts in your second output.